# Virtuemart 3 Products upload with csv file with images also, is any good component are module is there?

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

I need Good Joomla 3 Extensions for the Virtuemart 3  Products Bulk upload with Product images also.
is there any good component are module.

please suggest me the Extension **free** are Else **Paid**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any free extensions for importing products into VirtueMart.

I have used [CSVI Pro](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/csvi-pro) previously and this works well.

One of my clients is using the [Mass Update for Virtuemart](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/mass-update-for-virtuemart) to simplify product maintenance.

Searching the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org), I see there are other options but I can't vouch for any of these personally:

- [HexData Import & Export for Virtuemart](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-import-export)
- [VM Products CSV](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/vm-products-csv)

You can also check out [other import options in the VirtueMart Extensions Directory](http://extensions.virtuemart.net/import-export).